# jqGrid - jsonString datatype - Displaying nested json element values

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

All,

I'm having a JSON object which is being returned from a webservice. I'm using the Stringify method to convert it to a string object.

While I try to integrate this with my jqGrid, (using datatype:'jsonstring', datastr:myJSONstringobject). I'm able to map the JSON columns with the grid if it is straightforward (ie. 'index:customerName')

But if it is a nested JSON value (ie 'index:customer.customerAddress.street'), it is not getting loaded in the grid.

Can someone help?.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question correct you should use `jsonmap` property of column which contains dots (like `jsonmap: customer.customerAddress.street`) instead of `index`. If you use `datatype: 'jsonstring'` you should use `name` and `index` parameters with the same value which don't contains dots, spaces or any other meta-characters. Probably you can reduce the need to use `jsonmap` if you define `jsonReader` which corresponds your data. Because you don't posted the example of your JSON data I can't explain you more.

Mostly in case of the usage of webservices your don't need to use `datatype: 'jsonstring'`. Instead of that the usage of `datatype: 'json'` with some additional parameters would be better.

Comment: Thanks Oleg!.. Someday you should write a book on jqGrid for us!! :-)

Comment: @DavidR: You are welcome! Gladly I would write a book. I have to find more time for it only. Probably I'll start to publish some parts from the book.

Comment: @DavidR: Currently not, but it will be soon. I have to finish currents projects which I made for my customers first. :-)

Answer (score 1):

If you have nested JSON and you would like to display row data that it is in one of the children notes, you just use, for example if you have data for the "jqGrid" in the the "Data" node:

```
        jsonReader: {
            root: "data.rows",
            page: "data.page",
            total: "data.total",
            records: "data.records"
        }
```

Note: this is valid 100% on jqGrid version 4.4.4